# Not receiving notification from XPeria running Android 4.1

Tags: azure-notificationhub

Does notificationhubs have minimum requirement for Android OS? I'm testing my app on S6 Edge and Xperia, and Xperia is running 4.1(Api 16). I get test messages from S6 Edge but not from Xperia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue on Dell Android tablet. But after updating play service, the problem was solved. I didn't get to try that approach on Xperia phone though since it was taken away before I found that approach.

Answer (score 1):

According to GitHub repository ([1], [2]) of the Android SDK for Notification Hubs the minimum supported Android API version is 8.

To make sure that Xperia gets registered you can use `NotificationHubClient.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(100)` method from .NET SDK or REST API ([3]) to get all registrations in the notification hub. If the GCM registration id for Xperia is there, then try to use some third-party tool to send notification directly to this device, for example cURL ([4]). If you are able to send a direct notification to Xperia using a third-party tool, then please send namespace and notification hub name to nhubsupport@microsoft.com and I’ll take a look.

[1] https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/blob/cbc258af14d3bbf7480dff686ef522629d0563d7/Android/notification-hubs-sdk/build.gradle#L13

[2] https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/blob/cbc258af14d3bbf7480dff686ef522629d0563d7/Android/notification-hubs-sdk/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L8

[3] _https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/Dn223270.aspx

[4] _https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-07?hl=en

Comment: I tested it with push notification tester from playstore and it did not receive notification. It works with other phones I have. So I'm suspecting not having active sim card on that phone maybe the culprit.

Comment: It should work even without a sim card. Make sure that receiving push notifications is enabled on your device (if it possible to control it) and that your device is not in "low battery" mode.